# JQuery ("button").click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The example below works. (Example taken from w3cschools, and hacked a bit.)
Clicking anywhere in the DIV will cause the address class div to disappear.
However, changing the third line of the script to read

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

instead of "div" and it just sits there like a paperweight.  What am I missing.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".address").toggle("slow");

  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
div.ex
{
background-color:#e5eecc;
padding:7px;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Island Trading</h3>
<div class=ex>
    <button>Hide me</button>
  <div class=address>
    <p>Contact: Helen Bennett<br> 
    Garden House Crowther Way<br>
    London</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Paris spécialités</h3>
<div class=ex>
<button class="hide">Hide me</button>
<div class=address>
<p>Contact: Marie Bertrand<br> 
265, Boulevard Charonne<br>
Paris</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no children in the button element

Comment: To further explain, `$('button')` doesn't have children, and therefor when you try to get children with the class `.address` it doesn't find anything. You need to change the selector to something that will work.

Comment: this works as well according to your codes :     $(this).next(".address").toggle("fast");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$(this).children(".address").toggle("slow");
```

To something like:

```
$('.address').toggle("slow");
```

OR

```
$(this).siblings(".address").toggle("slow");
```

Once you make the listener act on the `button` element, `.address` is not a child of button any longer. It's a sibling. If there will be multiple `.address` classes on your page, you must use siblings.

http://jsfiddle.net/9S722/1/

Comment: Thanks!  I was just coming back to answer my own question.  Loading Firebug, and showing the exploded view of the html code showed me that <button> was a sibling of <div class=address> and not a parent.

It worked the first time because the selector chose the parent of <button>  Nice answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().children(".address").toggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/9S722/

Comment: Why not use siblings rather than travel up and back down the DOM?

Comment: @Leeish From a JavaScript perspective, how would you say the .siblings() jQuery function is built?

Comment: From the `write less, do more` perspective of jQuery, what's the point of jQuery if not to `write less`. one method call over two sounds better to me. If I wanted to know how the siblings function worked, I wouldn't be writing with jQuery, I'd be writing vanilla.

Comment: You say one method call over two sounds better, yet you choose to ignore the implementation of the methods. If you don't want to know how the siblings function worked, then how do you know the siblings method is not making two, three or four method calls?

Comment: I'm saying why write out two calls when one will do?  Especially if siblings jumps to parent and back down. The point of jQuery is to write less.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().children(".address").toggle("slow");
```

The button doesn't have children

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".address").toggle("slow");
});
```

The meaning of such code above is that, when click trigger in div container, it will go through its children for matching "address" class attribute.

However, if you just change $("div") to $("button"), but no child appears within button element. nothing matches for toggle function, just ignore it.

You should change code to as below:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".address").toggle("slow");
});
```

which find next sibling to button element. That is the element you want.